Creating a frequency table for each column in a data frame using a loop and storing the results in a list
I have a data frame, with each column containing data on group membership. For each column, I would like to calculate the frequency of each group in that column as well as the percentage of each group out of the total frequency for that particular column.
I would like the results (frequency table) to be stored in a list, with each element of the list being the result (frequency by group, percentage by group) for a particular column.
Here is what the data frame look like:
df <- data.frame(gender = c("male", "female", "", "male", "female"),
                 score1 = c(1, 1, NA, NA, 3),
                 score2 = c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 5),
                 score3 = c(2, 2, 3, 3, NA))

I have attempted the following code, which works on only 1 variable/column at a time.
countsbyvars <- function(var) {
  df %>%
    select({{var}}) %>%
    drop_na() %>%
    group_by({{var}}) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(freq = paste0(n / sum(n) * 100, "%"))
}

I would like to loop the column names of the data frame as input into the above user-generated function and store the result into a list.
I have attempted the following 3 pieces of code that I have written, but it does not working
# Using a for loop
res <- list()

for (i in names(df)) {
  res[i] <- countsbyvars(i)

Error in `group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
✖ Column `i` is not found.
}

# Using lapply to loop
lapply(df, countsbyvars(names(df)))

Error in `group_by()`:
ℹ In argument: `names(df)`.
Caused by error:
! `names(df)` must be size 0 or 1, not 317.

# Not sure how to use the across() function without hardcoding the column name

The end result would be something like this:
[[1]]

male | 2 | 50%
female | 2 | 50%

[[2]]

1 | 2 | 66.666666%
3 | 1 | 33.333333%

[[3]]

3 | 1 |33.33333%
4 | 1 | 33.33333%
5 | 1 | 33.33333%

[[4]]

2 | 2 | 50%
3 | 2 | 50%


v3
Probably increases performance:
lapply(names(df), \(i) {
  a = table(df[[i]]) |> as.data.frame()
  names(a)[1L] = i; x = sum(a$Freq) 
  a$Perc = sprintf("%.2f%%", 100L * a$Freq / x); a }) 

v2
Create tables with table and prop.table, combine to data.frame, and "setNames" in one lapply call:
lapply(seq_along(df), \(i) {
  a = table(df[[i]])
  b = sprintf("%.2f%%", round(prop.table(a), 4L)*100L)
  setNames(data.frame(a, b), c(names(df)[i], "Freq", "Perc")) })

#> [[1]]
#>   gender Freq   Perc
#> 1 female    2 50.00%
#> 2   male    2 50.00%
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   score1 Freq   Perc
#> 1      1    2 66.67%
#> 2      3    1 33.33%
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   score2 Freq   Perc
#> 1      3    1 33.33%
#> 2      4    1 33.33%
#> 3      5    1 33.33%
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   score3 Freq   Perc
#> 1      2    2 50.00%
#> 2      3    2 50.00%

Data
df <- data.frame(gender = c("male", "female", "", "male", "female"),
                 score1 = c(1, 1, NA, NA, 3),
                 score2 = c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 5),
                 score3 = c(2, 2, 3, 3, NA))
df[df == ""] = NA


My results require both the raw counts by group and the percentage by group, not just the percentage by group only. Thanks

You can use table() to calculate the counts, tibble::enfram() to convert each table into a dataframe, and transform() to obtain proportions. Here we take advantage of the feature that table ignores missing values by default.
Map(\(x, name) {
  tibble::enframe(c(table(x[x != ''])), name, "N") |>
    transform(Prop = proportions(N) * 100)
}, df, names(df), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

[[1]]
  gender N Prop
1 female 2   50
2   male 2   50

[[2]]
  score1 N     Prop
1      1 2 66.66667
2      3 1 33.33333

[[3]]
  score2 N     Prop
1      3 1 33.33333
2      4 1 33.33333
3      5 1 33.33333

[[4]]
  score3 N Prop
1      2 2   50
2      3 2   50


lapply(names(df), \(colname) {
  df[[colname]] |>
    table() |>
    as.data.frame() |>
    set_names(colname, "freq") |>
    mutate(perc = freq / sum(freq))
})


The original question shows how he's trying to do it in tidyverse syntax. And this is the most similar alternative to that syntax.

I'm not sure why you got downvoted, but I've upvoted your answer since it works too
